# about how to replicate igraph using ggraph

Tags: r, ggraph

I have a question.

How can I replicate network graphs using ggraph.
plot(g) is from igraph and ggraph()is from ggraph package.
I got a different figure. 
I am using weight, but how can I replicate a graph using ggraph??

```
# library
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
# create data:
links <- data.frame(
        source=c("A","A", "A", "A", "A","J", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D","I"),
        target=c("B","B", "C", "D", "J","A","E", "F", "G", "H", "I","I"),
        weight=(sample(1:20, 12, replace=T))

)
links$weight
nodes <- data.frame(
        name=LETTERS[1:10],
        carac=c( rep("young",3),rep("adult",2), rep("old",5))
)

# Turn it into igraph object
network <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=F) 

# Make a palette of 3 colors
library(RColorBrewer)
coul  <- brewer.pal(3, "Set1") 

# Create a vector of color
my_color <- coul[as.numeric(as.factor(V(network)$carac))]

library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
#

g<-tbl_graph(nodes, links, directed = FALSE)
# igraph
plot(g)

#ggraph
g %>% ggraph() +
        geom_node_point() +
        geom_edge_link()+geom_node_point(aes(colour = carac))+ geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE) +
        theme_graph()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? They have different ways of making plots—different default layouts, etc—so I'm not sure what you expect to be the same between the two

Comment: I just want to replicate plot(g) in this example using ggraph.

Comment: Is this correct?
```
graph <- as_tbl_graph(network)

ggraph(graph, layout = 'fr', weights = weight) + 
        geom_edge_link() + 
        geom_node_point()+geom_node_point(aes(colour =carac ))+geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE) +
        theme_graph()
```

Comment: You can [edit] the post to include more code. It's unclear what you're asking though, because you seem to already have 2 plots but haven't said exactly what you want to change